# Geocoder always returns List<> size 0

Tags: android

I have strange problem with Geocoder in Android.
I hardcoded lat and long on London and I am trying to get data from location like in Activity

```
 Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(this,Locale.getDefault());
int n=coder.getFromLocation(51.6, 0.083333, 1).size();
```

but I always get n=0, I have in manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"  />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION">
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION">
    </uses-permission>
```

Do I need something else to get this working ? I have enabled GPS.

Comment: Do you get any information about the GeoCoder in logcat? The geocoding API normally logs some information, if it does not find the location.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what happend to your side,
but i just copy and pated your code in my `Activity' onCreate() method` and it return me **n = 1**

also imported packges,

```
import java.util.Locale;
import android.location.Geocoder;
```

and in onCreate() simply written

```
    Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(this,Locale.getDefault()); 
     try {
        int n=coder.getFromLocation(51.6, 0.083333, 1).size();
        Log.i("SIZEEEEEEEEE", "==================="+n);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

here is my logcat output

```
11-02 16:07:29.618: INFO/SIZEEEEEEEEE(291): ===================1
```

*and yes for this i have not added any extra permission then Internet only.*