# addresses from Geocoder size is always zero

Tags: android, location, google-geocoder

i have the problem as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7978798/geocoder-always-returns-list-size-0) and i also did the same hardcoding for the lat and lon.

i get the exception to confirm the size as

```
Exception for the locationjava.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
```

When I try the same code on the Redmi a4, it works fine and give me the size as 1, and also the geocoding works fine, returning me all the addresses. The same code when I run on Lenovo it gives the exception. I checked the lat and lon and they have values which when i trace is pointing to my location. So what should I do to make the app run on both of the phones.
Lenovo phone running Android 4.4.4
Redmi running 6.0.0

```
if(lat != null && lon !=null) {
        try{

       Geocoder geocoder;
        List<Address> addresses;
        geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(dlat, dlon, 1); // Here 1 represent max location result to returned, by documents it recommended 1 to 5
        System.out.println("this is the size of address size"+addresses.size());
         String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0); // If any additional address line present than only, check with max available address lines by getMaxAddressLineIndex()
        String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
        String state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
        String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
        String postalCode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
        String knownName = addresses.get(0).getFeatureName();
        complete_address=address + "_" + city + "_" + address + "_" + postalCode + "_" + knownName + "_" + country;
        txtOutputLat.setText(complete_address);
        txtOutputLon.setText("Map Address");
    }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception for the location"+e.toString());

        }
    }
```

Comment: are u getting the lat long properly?

Comment: yes, in my app when i click on button it open the lat lan on the waze, which is working fine. Also when i trace them online it shows the same location i am in.

Answer (score 1):

Create this class and copy the code this works perfectly for me also this works in background and stops the main thread from ANR dialog

```
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.location.Address;
 import android.location.Geocoder;
 import android.os.AsyncTask;

 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.util.List;
 import java.util.Locale;


public class GetLocationAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
private String fulladdress = "";
private String smallAddress = "";
private String city = "";
private String state = "";
private String country = "";
private String zipcode = "";
private String placeName = "";

private AsyncResponse asyncResponseDelegate = null;
private   double x, y;
private Context context;

public interface AsyncResponse {
    void onProcessFinished(String fulladdress, String smallAddress, String state, String city, String country, String zipCode, String placeName);
}

public GetLocationAsync(double latitude, double longitude, final Context context, AsyncResponse asyncResponse) {
    x = latitude;
    y = longitude;
    this.context = context;
    this.asyncResponseDelegate = asyncResponse;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.ENGLISH);
    try {
        List<Address> addressList = geocoder.getFromLocation(x, y, 1);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        if (addressList != null && addressList.size() > 0) {
            Address address = addressList.get(0);
            fulladdress = "";
            smallAddress = "";
            placeName = "";
            if (sb.append(address.getAddressLine(0)) != null) {
                smallAddress = address.getAddressLine(0);
                fulladdress = smallAddress;
            }
            if (address.getLocality() != null) {
                city = address.getLocality();
                if (!fulladdress.contains(city))
                    fulladdress = fulladdress + " " + city;
            }
            if (address.getFeatureName() != null) {
                placeName = address.getFeatureName();
            }
            if (address.getAdminArea() != null) {
                state = address.getAdminArea();
                if (!fulladdress.contains(state))
                    fulladdress = fulladdress + " " + state;
            }
            if (address.getPostalCode() != null) {
                zipcode = address.getPostalCode();
                if (!fulladdress.contains(zipcode))
                    fulladdress = fulladdress + " " + zipcode;
            }
            if (address.getCountryName() != null) {
                country = address.getCountryName();
                if (!fulladdress.contains(country))
                    fulladdress = fulladdress + " " + country;
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    try {
        if (fulladdress != null && !fulladdress.isEmpty()) {
            asyncResponseDelegate.onProcessFinished(fulladdress, smallAddress, state, city, country, zipcode, placeName);
        } else {
            asyncResponseDelegate.onProcessFinished("", "", "", "", "", "", "");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
 }
```

to call this class

```
  GetLocationAsync locationAsync = new GetLocationAsync(latitude,
                                        longitude, getActivity(), new    GetLocationAsync.AsyncResponse() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onProcessFinished(String fulladdress, String smallAddress, String state, String city, String country, String zipCode, String placeName) {
                                        etAddress.setText(fulladdress);
                                    }
                                });
                                locationAsync.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens is when you try to get the postal code,city,country etc etc only from the address is that you might not recieve it for the very first time since its trying to get all zipcode, country, state and city from a single provider, which may not be available at times. Instead if you loop through the providers you may find it in one of them. Try this hope it helps!

```
               List<Address> addresses  = null;
                    try {
                        addresses =geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude,longitude, 5);

                        if (addresses.size() > 0) {

                            zipCode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
                            city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
                            country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
                            state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
                            address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
                            knownName = addresses.get(0).getFeatureName();


                            //if 1st provider does not have data, loop through other providers to find it.
                            int count = 0;
                            while ( count < addresses.size()) {
                                zipCode = addresses.get(count).getPostalCode();
                                    city= addresses.get(count).getLocality();
                            country = addresses.get(count).getCountryName();
                            state = addresses.get(count).getAdminArea();
                             address = addresses.get(count).getAddressLine(0);
                            knownName = addresses.get(count).getFeatureName();






                                count++;
                            }
                        }

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Comment: thing is that i always get the address as zero so it never move that part on the lenovo, on the redmi it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check for internet connection before calling geocoder.

```
    if(isConnectingToInternet(getContext()){
      //write your code of calling geocoder
     }


   public boolean isConnectingToInternet(Context context) {
    try {
        if (context != null) {
            ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            if (connectivity != null) {
                NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
                if (info != null)
                    for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                        if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                            return true;
                        }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStacktrace   
    }
    return false;
}
```